# Why interviewers are not satisfied with my QuickSort implementation in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, quicksort

Yesterday, on a job interview for a Junior iOS developer, I was asked to implement the QuickSort algorithm.

I wrote this:

```
func sort<T: Comparable>(_ array: Array<T>) -> Array<T> {

    let arraySize = array.count

    guard arraySize > 1 else { return array }

    let pivot = array[arraySize / 2]

    var less = [T]()
    var equal = [T]()
    var greater = [T]()

    for element in array {

        if element < pivot {
            less.append(element)
        } else if element > pivot {
            greater.append(element)
        } else {
            equal.append(element)
        }

    }

    return sort(less) + equal + sort(greater)

}
```

They said this is not QuickSort, but some *quicksortish* versions of it.
They suggested to go home and search for the real algorithm, despite I asked them to explain.

Like if you were the interviewer, what would you say about my code?

Comment: What's the deal with the interviewers and the QuickSort algorithm. They should move on to some other arbitrary algorithm applicants should learn by heart :)

Answer (score 1):

The only major issues I see is you are creating new arrays for every swap. So your memory usage will be m^2 vs just the array. Other than that I don't see a major issue with it but it has been a while since I have played with the quick sort.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @rhavelka. If I don't use additional arrays, to do the swapping I need to modify the parameter (side effect) and I have to use nested loops which will decrease performance in favour of memory. Am I right?

Comment: I don't think so? you should be able to pass the array in by reference. Then you can run it recursively and pass in the start/end index of your sub arrays

Answer (score 0):

You should do it in place. Select the last item as pivot, place all items smaller than pivot on the left, place others equal and bigger on the right, then place pivot at its place.

You can select any item as pivot but you should put pivot at correct position at each iteration and smaller numbers than pivot should be on the left size and others should be on the right side.

```
func quickSort<T: Comparable>(array: inout [T]) {
    quickSort(array: &array, startIndex: 0, endIndex: array.count-1)
}

func quickSort<T: Comparable>(array: inout [T], startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) {
    if startIndex >= endIndex {
        return
    }
    let itemIndex = partition(array: &array, startIndex: startIndex, endIndex: endIndex)
    quickSort(array: &array, startIndex: startIndex, endIndex: itemIndex-1)
    quickSort(array: &array, startIndex: itemIndex+1, endIndex: endIndex)
}

func partition<T: Comparable>(array: inout [T], startIndex: Int, endIndex: Int) -> Int {
    var i = startIndex
    for index in startIndex..<endIndex {
        if array[index] < array[endIndex] {
            array.swapAt(i, index)
            i += 1
        }
    }
    array.swapAt(i, endIndex)
    return i
}
```